# Token created via LogonUserW while impersonating another user is denied from accessing resources

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a program which creates tokens via `LogonUserW` and impersonates them while calling `RegOpenKeyW`. If I do this once the call to `RegOpenKeyW` will succeed. If I impersonate the 1st token, then make a 2nd token with `LogonUserW` and impersonate it, the same call to `RegOpenKeyW` will fail. Here is example code which demonstrates the behavior (note: the macros `USER` and `PASSWORD` are not included).

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void Test() {
    HKEY key;
    auto status{ RegOpenKeyW(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"*", &key) };
    std::wcout << L"RegOpenKeyW: ";
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::wcout << L"Succeeded";
        RegCloseKey(key);
    }
    else {
        std::wcout << L"Failed (0x" << std::hex << status << L")";
    }
    std::wcout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // Logon a user, impersonate them, then run a test
    HANDLE token1;
    if (LogonUserW(USER, L".", PASSWORD, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token1)) {
        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token1)) {
            Test();
            // While still impersonating the user, run the same actions
            HANDLE token2;
            if (LogonUserW(USER, L".", PASSWORD, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token2)) {
                if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token2)) {
                    Test();
                }
                CloseHandle(token2);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(token1);
    }
}
```

That generates the following output.

```
RegOpenKeyW: Succeeded
RegOpenKeyW: Failed (0x5)
```

Does anyone know why the 2nd call to `Test` fails with access denied (`0x5`)? I would expect that if the 1st call succeeded that the 2nd call would succeed as well but that is not the case.

If I use the same account for both calls to `LogonUserW`, I can inspected both tokens with [TokenViewer](https://github.com/googleprojectzero/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/tree/main/TokenViewer) and they appear to effectively be the same. However, I can use different accounts when calling `LogonUserW` and the same behavior will occur.

If I chose a different logon type or logon provider as the arguments to `LogonUserW` the same behavior will occur.

If I call `RevertToSelf` before the 2nd call to `LogonUserW` then both calls to `RegOpenKeyW` will succeed, but I am unsure why that change would allow it to succeed and the original example code will not.

I have also modified `Test` to access resources other than the registry (ex. `LsaOpenPolicy`) and have experienced the same behavior. The 1st attempt at accessing the resource will succeed and the 2nd attempt will fail.

Comment: I suspect WinApi doesn't support nested impersonations, thus calling `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` while you are already impersonating another user will fail. You said yourself that `RevertToSelf` fixes that. In general: you should only impersonate a user for as short an amount as possible, i.e. once you've performed the required operation, always call `RevertToSelf` immediately.

Comment: Windows allows you to call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` multiple times without any issue. So that should not be a problem with the provided example. As an example, if I call `LogonUserW` twice, then call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` followed by `Test()` for both tokens without calling `RevertToSelf` in between tests, then I will get `RegOpenKeyW: Succeeded` outputted both times.

Comment: after first call to `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`  you will be have `SecurityImpersonation` and after second call to `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`  with token with (another OriginatingLogonSession ) you will be have `SecurityIdentification` impersonation level. with this any security check will fail

Comment: of course this in case your process token have no `SeImpersonatePrivilege`. with this privilege - second call not will be reset to `SecurityIdentification` and open key not fail

Comment: if you have tool, which let show thread token - look for impersonation level of your thread after first and second impersonation

Comment: also will be another effect, if you change **order** of calls - first call `LogonUserW` 2 times and then `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` 2 times - in this case `OriginatingLogonSession` will be the same and again `SecurityImpersonation`

Comment: Thanks @RbMm! : ) That would make since, but when I check TokenViewer, each of the returned tokens in the original example are primary tokens and afaik do not have an impersonation level (TokenViewer lists the level as N/A). Are the impersonation levels you mentioned default impersonation levels Windows uses when you call `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` with a primary token returned by `LogonUserW` (or a similar API)?

Comment: It will take a moment to do, but I'll check the impersonation levels of the threads after each call like you recommended and report back 

Comment: you need look not token returned by `LogonUserW` - this is primary token, but look thread token

Comment: If you'd like to post your impersonation level comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here key point in [`SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ne-wdm-_security_impersonation_level) assigned to thread token. `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` internally call `SetThreadToken` 
-> [`PsImpersonateClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-psimpersonateclient) with `SecurityImpersonation` level, but internally this api call `SeTokenCanImpersonate` and if some conditions not meet :

> *The routine ensures whether client impersonation can actually occur by checking various conditions, including the following: ... If none
> of the conditions are met, the routine makes a copy of the existing
> token passed to the call and assigns the newly copied token as
> impersonation token albeit with **limited** security impersonation
> level; that is, the server thread can **only** obtain information
> about the client.*

in other words, the `SecurityImpersonation` replaced to `SecurityIdentification`

the list of conditions can be subject to change,but in general it next

- allow impersonating anonymous tokens
- allow if process token have ***SeImpersonatePrivilege***
- allow if ***AuthenticationId*** of process token equal to
  ***OriginatingLogonSession*** client token
- allow if tokens have equal security identifiers (SIDs)

when you call `LogonUserW` while no impersonate - the ***OriginatingLogonSession*** client token will be equal to ***AuthenticationId*** of process token. as result you will be always have `SecurityImpersonation` level after first `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`. but if you make second call to `LogonUserW` while you impersonating - the `token2` will be have **another *OriginatingLogonSession*** and if your process have no *SeImpersonatePrivilege* and you impersonate another user (not current, under which your process started) - after second call you will be have **SecurityIdentification**. with this - you can only check token properties but any security check will fail. opnkey, file, object with SD - all fail.

the POC code for test/check:

```
PCSTR ToString(TOKEN_TYPE TokenType)
{
    switch (TokenType)
    {
    case TokenPrimary:       return "      Primary";
    case TokenImpersonation: return "Impersonation";
    }

    __debugbreak();
    return 0;
}

PCSTR ToString(SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ImpersonationLevel)
{
    switch (ImpersonationLevel)
    {
    case SecurityAnonymous:      return "Anonymous     ";
    case SecurityIdentification: return "Identification";
    case SecurityImpersonation:  return "Impersonation ";
    case SecurityDelegation:     return "Delegation    ";
    }

    __debugbreak();
    return 0;
}

void PrintTokenInfo(HANDLE hToken)
{
    TOKEN_ORIGIN to;
    TOKEN_STATISTICS ts;
    ULONG cb;
    
    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenStatistics, &ts, sizeof(ts), &cb) &&
        GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenOrigin, &to, sizeof(to), &cb))
    {
        DbgPrint("%s:%s: %08x -> %08x\n", 
            ToString(ts.TokenType), ToString(ts.ImpersonationLevel), 
            to.OriginatingLogonSession.LowPart, ts.AuthenticationId.LowPart);
    }
}

void PrintTokenInfo()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken) ||
        OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, FALSE, &hToken))
    {
        PrintTokenInfo(hToken);
        CloseHandle(hToken);
    }
    else
    {
        DbgPrint("OpenThreadToken=%u\n", GetLastError());
    }
}

void m() {
    
    HANDLE token1, token2;
    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES|TOKEN_QUERY, &token1))
    {
        const TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = { 1, { { { SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE }, SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED } } };
        AdjustTokenPrivileges(token1, FALSE, const_cast<TOKEN_PRIVILEGES*>(&tp), sizeof(tp), 0, 0);
        DbgPrint("SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE=%u\n", GetLastError());
        PrintTokenInfo(token1);
        CloseHandle(token1);
    }

    if (LogonUserW(USER, L".", PASSWORD, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token1)) {
        PrintTokenInfo(token1);
        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token1)) {
            PrintTokenInfo();
            if (LogonUserW(USER, L".", PASSWORD, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token2)) {
                PrintTokenInfo(token2);
                if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token2)) {
                    PrintTokenInfo();
                }
                CloseHandle(token2);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(token1);
    }

    RevertToSelf();
}
```

if run this code under elevated admin process:

```
SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE=0
      Primary:Anonymous     : 000003e7 -> 0003dafa
      Primary:Impersonation : 0003dafa -> 0107cb0a
Impersonation:Impersonation : 0003dafa -> 0107cb0a
      Primary:Impersonation : 0107cb0a -> 0107cbba
Impersonation:Impersonation : 0107cb0a -> 0107cbba
```

and if run under restricted(not elevated) user

```
SE_IMPERSONATE_PRIVILEGE=1300 // ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED
      Primary:Anonymous     : 000003e7 -> 0003dbc5
      Primary:Impersonation : 0003dbc5 -> 01064877
Impersonation:Impersonation : 0003dbc5 -> 01064877
      Primary:Impersonation : 01064877 -> 010648ee
OpenThreadToken=1346 // ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
```

last error ( ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL ) say that real impersonation level of our thread is `SecurityIdentification`. this also can be checked by another, elevated tool

Comment: Thank you @RbMm! That makes sense and I appreciate the writeup! 